# GUI apps in python 3.4

Tags: python, qt

I've been looking for a GUI system for python applications for a while and have found these 2, Tkinter and PyQT. The issue I'm having is that I cannot work out whether PyQT requires the end user to have QT installed and whether Tkinter will work properly on another computer as I have read a lot about it being touchy when it comes to Tk/Tcl version.

What I'm trying to do with it is create an application for a friend so that he can keep track of his beehives more easily and I didn't think that having it in a terminal would be the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104766/release-python-executable-with-dependency-on-python-bindings-of-a-c-library ....not exact answer to yours...but it may help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with both in the past and from my observations:

> whether PyQT requires the end user to have QT installed

Yes, it does. However you can bundle your app along with the dependencies (Python + QT) using tools like PyInstaller. You will get a single package that you can distribute to your users. They can run it without installing anything.

You can also create custom installers which install Python and QT on the target systems for you. Then the users can just run the Python script.

> whether Tkinter will properly on another computer as I have read a lot
>   about it being touchy when it comes to Tk/Tcl version

I have never faced any issues with it since I mostly deployed my Tkinter apps to Windows and I installed the same version of Python on the target systems that I used to develop. However, there might be version conflicts on other platforms (eg. Linux/OS X).

> What I'm tying to do with it is create an application for a friend so
>   that he can keep track of his beehives more easily

Have you thought about web based GUI? A python script running a webserver on a local machine? You can use the "webbrowser" module to open up a browser to load the url when the script is run.

There is another alternative: [Kivy](http://kivy.org/).

Comment: In response to the WebGUI thing. I'm not sure about how to integrate python into html as I haven't learnt most of the useful web scripting languages like Javascript and php. Thank's for the answer though. It was quite helpful

Comment: @MessyMasseyStudios You can try a micro framework like Flask. You won't need PHP since you will work with Python here. Familiarity with HTML, JS, CSS would be needed however.

Comment: Thanks. I've since started to work on learning to use flask. It's been great so far